# Browser-based mobile notifications

Tags: iphone, android, html, symbian, mobile-website

I would like to schedule alerts to the users to remind people of certain recurring tasks such as meet with dentist, clean trash etc.  I want to do this using a browser based (HTML 5?) app which can run akin to a daemon process by leaving the browser window open, and warning the user against closing it if they try to 'x' it.

Is this possible at all? If so, how can one alert the user periodically on multiple mobile platforms (Symbian, iPhone, Android, WP7 etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [Sencha Touch HTML5 Framework](http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch/)

with using PhoneGap together.

Comment: would you mind providing some additional details on how we might approach it?

Comment: would you like to do a cross-platform working app or just a browser based app? So, this framework which i can help you to give some info about it is help you to create cross-platform app development (not for win7) app work on browser but it is still an native application.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at appcelerator and phonegap.